# Is it possible to create a social network where data is stored on user's computer?

Tags: electron, webrtc, client-side, indexeddb, social-networking

I'm searching a way to make a **social network** where the data (images, videos...) is stored on the **user's computer** (or client-side) and a remote server is used to access it by **serving the functionnality and the design**. The basic thing would be for each user to have a profile and to be able to browse other's profiles.

*Note* : It's not a problem if the client-side computer shuts down its machine. The user's profile would be just designed as offline. And when the user is connected, others would be able to browse his – her profile.

I searched a lot and I came up with different ideas :

**→** store data with indexeddb and then stream it with webrtc. The problem : webrtc is not really made for showing a simple profile page to be browsed by multiple users.

**→** make a desktop app to access local files and then try to make a communication with the server to deliver the app (with something like electron ?). The problem is I don't know if electron is well suited for this kind of project.

Any ideas, questions, suggestions, remarks or anything that helps would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: This question is too broad and open-ended for SO. We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and the other Help pages for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I did everything possible to make a receivable question. I'll definitely check the link you provided for next questions.

Answer (score 0):

We have an application which i a Cloud Screen service/application. The purpose of the application is to store images and videos locally but also on the server. So if a computer connects to the network, it'll download the current content (json, images, videos) so it can display these even without internet because it's stored locally.

The client was made in Electron and the management application was .NET Core.
If you're thinking about creating a desktop application, then yes, it is possible, but in order to achieve this, you have to store on the server as well.

Let's assume that someone wants to check your profile. It has to load your datas which has to be stored on the server because they can't access your local files and computer. But you can store your files locally to boost up the speed.

I would only recommend this to store images/videos and bigger files, but you have to specify your requirements because in this case, every time you bump into a new content, you have to download it (if you want to store locally so it'll load faster the stored files).

The second option is to store these in the client. But be aware, desktop application's size can increase easily with lots of images and videos. If you store these in the client, you only have to store the URLs in case of dynamic datas (static URLs can be stored as static data).

I hope I could help, if you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In fact, the thing is to avoid to store data on server because it will always be growing and it's much more earth-friendly for the users to store their own data. Do you think it is possible to make this kind of decentralized memory with Electron ?

Comment: I still suggest to use a DB for storing datas because as you mentioned, it’s meant to be a social network app, so you need more people’s data and not only yours. Store videos and images on the server BUT not in the DB. It’s the best thing to be able to create a social network app.

Comment: Yes, I understand that a classical client-server model would be much more easier and kind of a logic architecture for a social network. The simple problem that still remains is that you have to host all that growing data. Even if I have a small community, they would keep going to post data almost everyday or at least often so we return back to the growing data problem. But just want to give a try on "decentralized memory". If it does not work, I will for sure return back to the traditionnal way.